# How to synchronize stored procedure in SQL Server and stored procedure in a solution in Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures, source-control-explorer

I have about 250 stored procedures in database A in SQL Server. I have a solution containing several projects in Visual Studio. One project inside that solution saves/source controls about 200 stored procedures. These 200 stored procedures are from database A.

I would like to source control all the 250 stored procedures, my questions now are:

1. How can I add the remaining 50 stored procedures from database A to the project inside that solution? I can do it manually but is there any quicker way or easier way to do it?
2. How can I synchronize stored procedures in SQL Server and stored procedures in a solution in Visual Studio? For example, if I make a change to a stored procedure in SQL Server, then Visual Studio should detect the change and let me save the new version easily in SQL Server and Visual Studio.

Comment: Is there a reason your question seems to be absolutely unaware of database projects and their schema sync functionality in visual studio? There is a whole project type for this stuff.

Comment: Oh I did not know this.